# Umbraco:custom drop down

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7

I am trying to create a custom datatype in Umbraco V7.4.3
its a Dropdown where the prevalues which will be fetched from Sql statement.
i am able to create Dropdown

```
 [PropertyEditor(PropertyEditorConstants.SqlDropDownAlias, " Sql DropDown", "/App_Plugins/CustomDataType/DropDown/DropDownEditor.html", ValueType = "TEXT")]
        [PropertyEditorAsset(ClientDependencyType.Javascript, "/App_Plugins/CustomDataType/DropDown/DropDownEditor.controller.js")]

     public  class SqlDropDownPropertyEditor:BasePropertyEditor 
            {
                protected override PreValueEditor CreatePreValueEditor()
                {
                    return new SqlDropDownPreValueEditor();
                }
            }
```

any idea on how to provide SQL expression box in the data type and process it ?

Answer (score 5):

This functionality can be easily provided by a great package called nuPickers so shouldn't require you to write a custom property editor. https://our.umbraco.org/projects/backoffice-extensions/nupickers/

Comment: Big recommendations for this package! We have managed to solve so many of our issues by adding this feature.